# Access parent data model in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive to check for double values in a data column:

The markup

```
<table>
   <tr data-ng-repeat-start="rowItem in vm.model.data" ...>
      <td>
         <input type="text" data-ng-model="rowItem.ID" data-unique-column="vm.model.data" />
      </td>
      ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

and the directive

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').directive('uniqueColumn', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.on('keyup blur', function () {

                    scope.$eval(attrs.uniqueColumn).forEach(function (item) {
                        // validation logic
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

Everything works fine but I asked myself if there was a solution to access the data of my repeater, i.e. vm.model.data, without passing an argument to the directive?

Comment: Have you tried scope.$parent.vm.model.data ?

Comment: Yes, but I hoped there is a more generic solution where I don't need to know the name of the data object.

Comment: Isn't `scope.$eval(attrs.uniqueColumn)` already doing that for you?

Comment: Only if I pass the argument in the call of the directive. But that's what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Comment: There's no generic way to access the iterable model of the ngRepeat (e.g. _vm.model.data_). You need to define it somehow/somewhere. Check if my response below helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't isolate the scope, you can read javascript's prototypal inheritance. You can perhaps access a method from the child that will then lookup to the parent's. And perhaps use the $index as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use another directive to define the unique-column's model and add it as a dependency on the unique-column directive, like this:

**unique-column-model directive:**

```
app.directive('uniqueColumnModel', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: function($scope) {
        // add more logic here if necessary
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        // save the value of the uniqueColumnModel as a private var in the scope
        scope.$uniqueColumnModel = scope.$eval(attrs.uniqueColumnModel);
      }
  };
});
```

**unique-column directive:**

```
app.directive('uniqueColumn', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      // set the uniqueColumnModel directive as a dependency (^ is to search on parents)
      require: ['ngModel', '^uniqueColumnModel'],
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.on('keyup blur', function () {
            // use the private $uniqueColumnModel var that was
            // previously saved on the scope
            angular.forEach(scope.$uniqueColumnModel, function(item) {
                // validation logic
            });
        });
      }
  };
});
```

And on the HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.items" unique-column-model="model.items">
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.id" unique-column />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JjMPvhrJqpvi11xETfyQ).

There's still room for improvement but the idea is there...